# Diffeomorphism between two manifolds and a differential function in a neighborhood of $\varphi(p)$

Tags: manifolds

> Let $M$ be a manifold in $\mathbb R^n$. Observe that if $\varphi : M \to M$ is a diffeomorphism, $v \in T_p M$ and $f$ is a differentiable function in a neighborhood of $\varphi(p)$, we have
>   $$
> (d\varphi(v)f)\varphi(p) = v(f \circ \varphi)(p).
> $$
>   Indeed, let $\alpha : (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to M$ be a differentiable curve with $\alpha'(0)=v$, $\alpha(0)=p$. Then
>   $$
> (d\varphi(v)f)\varphi(p) = \frac d{dt}(f \circ \varphi \circ \alpha) \Bigg\vert_{t=0} = v(f \circ \varphi)(p).
> $$

(from do Carmo, *Riemannian geometry*, page 26)

I am trying to justify the last very last equality. When I applied the chain rule, I have that
$$
\frac d{dt}(f \circ \varphi \circ \alpha) = f'(\varphi \circ \alpha(t))\varphi'(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t).
$$
Substituting in $t=0$ gives
$$
\frac d{dt}(f \circ \varphi \circ \alpha)\bigg\vert_{t=0} = f'(\varphi(p))\varphi'(p)v,
$$
but this is not the desired final expression $v(f \circ \varphi)(p)$. I am getting prime symbols, but $v(f \circ \varphi)(p)$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is old but maybe someone might stumble across and find this useful.

This is a usual misunderstanding when talking about tangent vectors as operators.

Now in our setting we have the following equality that we both agree on:
$$d\varphi(v)(f)(\varphi(p))=\frac{d}{dt}f\circ\varphi\circ \alpha \Big|_{t=0}$$

We have that $\alpha’(0)=v$, thus by the very definition of $v$ (as an operator acting on a function) we obtain:
$$v(f)=\frac{d}{dt} f\circ \alpha \Big|_{t=0}$$
So by definition of the tangent vector applied to $f\circ \varphi$ we see:

$$v(f\circ \varphi)= \frac{d}{dt} (f\circ\varphi\circ \alpha)\Big|_{t=0}=  d\varphi(v)(f)(\varphi(p))$$
In this case there is nothing to justify it is all a matter of definitions :)